# Scraping Vaccination Data using BeautifulSoup (python)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am new to scraping :) . I would like to scrape a website to get information about vaccination. Here is the website:https://ourworldindata.org/covid-vaccinations

My goal is to obtain the table with three columns:

- "Country"
- "Share of people fully vaccinated against COVID-19"
- "Share of people only partly vaccinated against COVID-19"

Here is my code:

```
# importing basic libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# request for getting the target html.
def get_html(URL):
    scrape_result = requests.get(URL)
    return scrape_result.text
vac_html = get_html("https://ourworldindata.org/covid-vaccinations")

# the BeautifulSoup library for scraping the data, with "html.parser" for parsing.
beatiful_soup = BeautifulSoup(vac_html, "html.parser")

# view the html script.
print(beatiful_soup.prettify())

# finding the content of interest 
get_table = beatiful_soup.find_all("tr")

for x in get_table:
    print("*********")
    print(x)
```

Current output: The entire webpage as HTML. This is a fraction of it :

```
'\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if !IE]><!-->\n<html lang="en">\n<!--<![endif]-->\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">\n<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">\n<title>COVID Live Update: 261,656,911 Cases and 5,216,375 Deaths from the Coronavirus - Worldometer</title>\n<meta name="description" content="Live statistics and coronavirus news tracking the number of confirmed cases, recovered patients, tests, and death toll due to the COVID-19 coronavirus from Wuhan, China. Coronavirus counter with new cases, deaths, and number of tests per 1 Million population. Historical data and info. Daily charts, graphs, news and updates">\n\n<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">\n<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">\n<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">\n<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png">\n<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png">\n<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114"
```

Unfortunately, it is not producing the information I liked to see. Does anyone have some experience in web scraping and could quickly review my code?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's you current output? please edit you question and include it

Comment: I am getting the html of the entire webpage, I will edit it in the question, thanks !

Comment: I have updated the question, sorry I am fairly new to posting on StackOverflow

Comment: any tips on how I can post better to not get downvoted are more than welcome :) I am fairly new to the community. Thank you

Comment: For what i saw those informations are fetched dynamically once the site is loaded, using the chrome dev tools on network tab they're fetching it from [here](https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/internal/megafile--vaccinations-bydose.json) which is where you'll probably have to scrape.

Comment: cool! I will try it out, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just took a quick look at that website. I suggest instead of using beautiful soup, you should just use the request that they are using to get the data.
In the network request ([viewed using dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TqdT.png)) you will find a GET request to https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/internal/megafile--vaccinations.json
you can go back to the site yourself and try this. If you go to that link above you can see that it returns a nice JSON object that you can parse.

Comment: it makes sense! Thanks for your tip

Answer (score 1):

It's all there if you get the data directly from the source:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/internal/megafile--vaccinations-bydose.json"
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
          location  ... people_partly_vaccinated_per_hundred
0      Afghanistan  ...                             0.987197
1      Afghanistan  ...                             0.986009
2      Afghanistan  ...                             0.952562
3      Afghanistan  ...                             0.924529
4      Afghanistan  ...                             0.918366
           ...  ...                                  ...
30218     Zimbabwe  ...                             6.310471
30219     Zimbabwe  ...                             6.384688
30220     Zimbabwe  ...                             6.429645
30221     Zimbabwe  ...                             6.429439
30222     Zimbabwe  ...                             6.447568

[30223 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you for your help